# TikZ: How to add additional text to datavisualization.formats.functions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

My code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes,
                       visualize as smooth line/.list = {
                                                         degressiv,
                                                         linear,
                                                         progressiv
                                                        },
                       style sheet = vary dashing,
                       degressiv = {
                                    label in legend = {text = degressiv}
                                   },
                       linear = {
                                 label in legend = {text = linear}
                                },
                       progressiv = {
                                     label in legend = {text = progressiv}
                                    }
                      ]
    data[set = degressiv] {
                           x,    y
                           0,    0
                            .45,  .75
                           1,    1
                          }
    data[set = linear] {
                        x, y
                        0, 0
                        1, 1
                       }
    data[set = progressiv] {
                            x,   y
                            0,   0
                             .6,  .25
                            1,   1
                           };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: result]

I wish:

[image: wish]

How can I do it?

Thank you for your effort in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added two lines at the end.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes,
                       visualize as smooth line/.list = {
                                                         degressiv,
                                                         linear,
                                                         progressiv
                                                        },
                       style sheet = vary dashing,
                       degressiv = {
                                    label in legend = {text = degressiv},
                                   },
                       linear = {
                                 label in legend = {text = linear}
                                },
                       progressiv = {
                                     label in legend = {text = progressiv},
                                    }
                      ]
    data[set = degressiv] {
                           x,    y
                           0,    0
                            .45,  .75
                           1,    1
                          }
    data[set = linear] {
                        x, y
                        0, 0
                        1, 1
                       }
    data[set = progressiv] {
                            x,   y
                            0,   0
                             .6,  .25
                            1,   1
                           }
                          info{
    \node(Ustar) at (visualization cs: x=0.1, y=0.8) {$U^*$};
    \node(U) at (visualization cs: x=0.8, y=0.1) {$U$};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @marmot! Thank you for your answer! This is an easy solution. But is it possible to use options/keys of `datavisualization.formats.functions` from `TikZ`? I think it is more elegant and intuitive to do so (if even possible), but I don't know how.

Comment: @Su-47 Very good point! Please see my update!

Comment: Hello @marmot! Thank you for your comment and update! This looks great!